# no getting id i have two if conditions getting id for one condition and not getting id for another in the same page

Tags: php

Try to get 'id' and getting from url (?id=) it in case 1
Trying to get 'id' but not getting it in case 2
Please help me with this as it was a strange problem 
Getting id in one case and not getting id on another case of the same page

```
         <?php
            include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/config.inc.php');
            include_once(TEMPLATES_ROOT_PATH . 'admin_header.php');
            $pageTitle="New User";
            include_once(CLASS_ROOT_PATH . '/AdminClass.php');
            $adminObject = new AdminClass();

            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            $editusers = $adminObject->getEditUsers($_GET['id']); //case1 - Getting id
            }
            if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            $updateuserdata = array(
                    "user_name" => $_POST['username'],
                    "user_email" => $_POST['email'],
                    "user_phone" => $_POST['phone'],
                    "user_city" => $_POST['city'],
                    "role" => $_POST['role']
                );
            $editDetails = $adminObject->updateUsers($updateuserdata,$_GET['id']); //case2 - Not getting id (Please Help..)

            echo "<script>";
            echo "location.replace('/admin/users.php')";
            echo "</script>";

            }
            ?>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Edit User Details| </title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <meta name="description" content="Admin panel developed with the Bootstrap from Twitter.">
                <meta name="author" content="travis">

                <link href="<?php echo CSS_ROOT_PATH; ?>/admin_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="<?php echo CSS_ROOT_PATH; ?>/admin_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="<?php echo CSS_ROOT_PATH; ?>/admin_bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

              </head>
              <body>


                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span3">
                      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                          <li class="nav-header"><i class="icon-wrench"></i> Administration</li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="users.php">Users</a></li>
                          <li><a href="roles.php">Roles</a></li>

                          <!--li><a href="stats.php">General</a></li>
                          <li><a href="user-stats.php">Users</a></li>
                          <li><a href="visitor-stats.php">Visitors</a></li-->
                          <li class="nav-header"><i class="icon-user"></i> Profile</li>
                          <li><a href="my-profile.php">My profile</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="<?PHP ECHO MODULES_ROOT_PATH?>/admin/index.php">Logout</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>        
            <div class="span9">
                              <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="page-header">
                                            <h1>Edit User Details</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action ="/admin/edit-user.php">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                                                            <div class="controls">
                                                                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="username" value="<?php echo $editusers[0]['user_name'] ?>"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>
                                                            <div class="controls">
                                                                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $editusers[0]['user_email'] ?>"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label" for="pnohe">Phone</label>
                                                            <div class="controls">
                                                                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $editusers[0]['user_phone'] ?>"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
                                                            <div class="controls">
                                                                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $editusers[0]['user_city'] ?>"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>  
                                                    <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label" for="role">Role</label>
                                                            <div class="controls">
                                                                    <select id="role" name="role">
                                                                           <?php if($editusers[0]['role']==""){ ?>
                                                                            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                                                                            <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
                                                                            <option value="User" selected>User</option>
                                                                      <?php
                                                                             }
                                                                    ?>
                                                            <?php if($editusers[0]['role']=="Administrator"){ ?>
                                    <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                                <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
                                               <option value="User">User</option>
                              <?php
                                              }
                                              ?> 
                                                            <?php if($editusers[0]['role']=="Moderator"){ ?>
                                    <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
                                <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                                               <option value="User">User</option>
                              <?php
                                              }
                                              ?> 
                                                    <?php if($editusers[0]['role']=="User"){ ?>
                                    <option value="User">User</option>
                                <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                                               <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
                              <?php
                                              }
                                              ?> 
                                                                    </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>  

                                                    <div class="form-actions">
                                                    <button class="btn" id="submit" name="update" value="update">Update</button>
                                                    <a class="btn" href="users.php">Cancel</a>
                                                    </div>                  
                                            </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <script src="<?php echo JS_ROOT_PATH; ?>/admin_jquery.js"></script>
                    <script src="<?php echo JS_ROOT_PATH; ?>/admin_bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <?php
            include_once(TEMPLATES_ROOT_PATH . 'admin_footer.php');
            ?>
```

Comment: The first case, you are checking if the id isset.  The second you are not.  Are you sure the id is set in the second case? Are you confusing `$_GET` with `$_POST`?

Comment: iam using $_POST['update'] because update is button and form method is post. iam using $_GET because iam getting the id from url

Answer (score 0):

By not getting, do you mean that $editDetails is null, or that null is passed as the second argument to 
    $adminObject->updateUsers($updateuserdata,$_GET['id'])?

If the first case is the $_POST['update'] set?

Comment: Actually the 'id' is not coming by using $_GET['id']. So no values are getting retrieved. if i hardcode it by any no like 5 for example $adminObject->updateUsers($updateuserdata,5); Its working fine meaning there is problem getting id. but in case 1 it was working fine. means id is getting to this page but not understanding why it fails in case 2

Comment: So what do you get if you var_dump($_GET['id']) before updateUsers?